# Botão 'Carregar mais' duplica ou não funciona AJAX/JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Opa pessoal, tudo certo?

Seguinte, eu tenho uma tabela que é alimentada com conteúdo de um arquivo externo em JSON (criado a partir do PHP com dados vindos do DB). Ao abrir o site, a tabela vem com apenas 2 registros e ao clicar em 'Carregar mais' mais 2 registros são adicionados a tabela.

O modo como eu ordeno o array é através do ID único do DB, então se houver uma exclusão de registro, ele fica vazado (ex: 0|1|3|6|7|8) o que faz o 'carregar mais' não funcionar ou duplicar os dados.

Eu fiz um fix, porém eu preciso criar um novo ID no JSON para ordenar tudo novamente, mantendo a contagem constante. Então gostaria de saber como optimizar ou fixar meu código para poder funcionar SEM o fix, ou seja, utilizando o ID, em ordem crescente, mesmo que não seja sequencial, como no exemplo citado acima.

Este é o meu código jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "data/results.json";

    $.getJSON(url, function (response){
        $.each (response, function (index, table) {
            loopTable(index <= 1, index, table);
        }); //end each
    }); //end getJSON

    function loopTable(test, index, table){
        var write;
        if(test){

            write += '<tr class="count">';
            write += '<td>' + table.name + '</td>';
            write += '<td>' + table.data + '</td>';
            if (table.status === true) {
                write += '<td class="ap">Aprovado</td>'; 
            } else {
                write += '<td class="ng">Negado</td>';
            }
            write += '<td>' + table.id + '</td>';
            write += '<td><button class="bt_delete">Deletar</button></td>';
            write += '</tr>';

            $('#mytable').append(write);
        }
    }; //end function       

    $('.more').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var galleryLength = $('.count').length;
        $.ajax(url, {
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                if(data){
                    var jsonLength = data.length; 
                }
                $.each(data, function(index, table){
                    loopTable(table.id >= galleryLength && table.id < galleryLength + 2, index, table);
                    if ( table.id.length == galleryLength ) {
                        $('.more').hide();
                    };
                });
            },
            error:  function(){
                $('#myerro').append('<h3>Desculpe, houve um problema.</h3>');
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.more').hide();
                $('.spinner').fadeIn();
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('.spinner').hide();
                $('.more').fadeIn();
            }
        }); //end ajax
    }); //end click
}); //end ready
```

Comment: Os ids no JSON que vem do PHP estão sempre em ordem crescente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que os `id`s que estão no JSON que vem do PHP estão em ordem crescente (o que faz mais sentido), eu acho que você precisa rastrear qual foi o último `id` caregado. Também é bom dar um jeito para garantir que o `loopTable` leia apenas dois registros. Para isso:

1. Adicione uma variável, `lastId`:

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var url = "data/results.json";
       var lastId = -1;
   ```
2. Retire o teste do `loopTable` e rastreie o `lastId` lá. Também é importante inicializar a variável `write` adequadamente:

   ```js
       function loopTable(index, table){
           var write = '';
           write += '<tr class="count">';
           write += '<td>' + table.name + '</td>';
           write += '<td>' + table.data + '</td>';
           if (table.status === true) {
               write += '<td class="ap">Aprovado</td>'; 
           } else {
               write += '<td class="ng">Negado</td>';
           }
           write += '<td>' + table.id + '</td>';
           write += '<td><button class="bt_delete">Deletar</button></td>';
           write += '</tr>';

           $('#mytable').append(write);
           lastId = table.id;
       }; //end function
   ```
3. Temos que garantir que quando o `loopTable` for chamado pela primeira vez, que ele vá ler os dois primeiros registros, não importando quais forem os `id`s, afinal tem que funcionar mesmo se os elementos com `id`s 0 e 1 tiverem sido removidos:

   ```js
       $.getJSON(url, function (response) {
           var carregados = 0;
           $.each (response, function (index, table) {
               loopTable(index, table);
               carregados++;
               if (carregados == 2) return false;
           }); //end each
       }); //end getJSON
   ```
4. Não use o `galleryLength`. Ao invés disso, use o `lastId`:

   ```js
       $('.more').on('click', function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           $.ajax(url, {
   ```

   ```js
                   var lastLoaded = lastId;
                   var carregados = 0;
                   $.each(data, function(index, table) {
                       if (table.id <= lastLoaded) return true;
                       loopTable(index, table);
                       carregados++;
                       if (carregados == 2) return false;
                   });
   ```
5. Acho que este trecho está errado, e nem deveria estar ali, pelo menos não vejo sentido dele estar dentro do `$.each(...)`:

   ```js
                       if ( table.id.length == galleryLength ) {
                           $('.more').hide();
                       };
   ```

Além disso, há uma observação importante a se fazer. O PHP está trazendo todos os registros, convertendo todos em JSON, tudo está sendo transmitindo pela rede/internet e o javascript está recebendo tudo isso para só então filtrar. Seria muito melhor você fazer a filtragem do lado do PHP, aonde seria enviado por AJAX o id do último registro carregado e o número de registros a carregar, e então o PHP enviaria apenas os registros requisitados.

Comment: O ID que vem do PHP está sim em ordem crescente, porém não ordenada. Como houve exclusão de alguns registros, ele fica tipo 1,2,4,5,7,9... Quanto as alterações, eu fiz, porém não acontece nada. Ele apenas fica dando loading eterno. Inverti os sinais de '`>`' e '`<=`' para '`<`' e '`>=`' e ele carrega. No entanto ele carrega apenas 1 registro e é um registro duplicado do último exibido.

Comment: @celsomtrindade Editei a minha resposta. Veja se agora dá certo.

Comment: Está começando a funcionar, porém parou de carregar no ID 9. Carrega até o ID 9, na hora de carregar do 10 em diante, ele não carrega mais. Ps.: sou novo com ajax/jquery, tentei mudar alguns números e sinais, mas não consegui o resultado.

Comment: @celsomtrindade Tem certeza que o id é um número e não uma string? Se você mostrar um pouco de como é o seu JSON isso deve ficar bem claro.

Comment: Não sabia desse detalhe do JSON, fiz o fix e funcionou. Agora, aparentemente, está tudo perfeito! Vou fazer mais alguns testes, mas pelo que vi até o momento, está ok! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!